# Create Unresolved Tasks/Contacts/etc through the REST API?

Tags: rest-api

Is this possible? I have found a few results googling this, but only of people asking the question, never answering it.

Comment: what defines an 'unresolved'record?

Comment: Something that shows up in the My Unresolved Items section.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, I cannot find any reference to unresolved in the apex language reference guide, there is nothing useful online that I can find either apart from a way to query unresolved tasks (subject name LIKE '%Unresolved'). People have stated that even cloning those records doesn't work in terms as marking unresolved. My best guess is that a hidden field manages it and salesforce restrict access for whatever reason. Maybe raise a case to support / start an idea to open up access to that functionality.

// Link to unresolved items for those that have not seen it.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=outlookcrm_unresolved_items.htm&language=en

Comment: Damn. This is the conclusion I had reached as well. Was hoping someone had access to some arcane lore that I wasn't privy to.